# Call to options has different side effects dependening on how it is called

Tags: r

I'd like to have a function that sets `repos` and `pktType` options

Somehow a call to `options()` seems to have different side effects depending on how it is called - and I would like to understand the cause of it.

This is the unit test for `set_options()`:

```
set_options <- function(
  repos = c(RSPM = "https://packagemanager.rstudio.com/all/__linux__/focal/latest"),
  pkgType = "binary"
) {
  options(
    repos = repos,
    pkgType = pkgType
  )
}

library(testthat)

test_that("Set options", {
  actual <- set_options()
  print(actual)

  expected <- list(
    repos = c(RSPM = "https://packagemanager.rstudio.com/all/__linux__/focal/latest"),
    pkgType = "binary"
  )

  expect_identical(actual, expected)

  expect_identical(getOption("repos"), expected$repos)
  expect_identical(getOption("pkgType"), expected$pkgType)
})
```

It works as desired when executing the code interactively or when sourcing it via `source("path/to/file.R")`:

```
source("tests/testthat/test-options.R")
# $repos
#                                                           RSPM 
# "https://packagemanager.rstudio.com/all/__linux__/focal/latest" 
#
# $pkgType
# [1] "binary"
#
# Test passed
```

However, when I run the test via `devtools::test()` I get the following result:

```
[...]
⠏ |   0       | options                                                                 $repos
CRAN 
"@CRAN@" 

$pkgType
[1] "source"

x |   2 1     | options [0.2 s]                                                         
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Failure (test-options.R:22:3): Set options
`actual` (`actual`) not identical to `expected` (`expected`).

`names(actual$repos)`:   "CRAN"
`names(expected$repos)`: "RSPM"

`actual$repos`:   "@CRAN@"                                                       
`expected$repos`: "https://packagemanager.rstudio.com/all/__linux__/focal/latest"

`actual$pkgType`:   "source"
`expected$pkgType`: "binary"
```

And when I wrap it with `reprex::reprex()`, I get this:

```
library(testthat)

set_options <- function(
  repos = c(RSPM = "https://packagemanager.rstudio.com/all/__linux__/focal/latest"),
  pkgType = "binary"
) {
  options(
    repos = repos,
    pkgType = pkgType
  )
}

test_that("Set options", {
  actual <- set_options()
  print(actual)

  expected <- list(
    repos = c(RSPM = "https://packagemanager.rstudio.com/all/__linux__/focal/latest"),
    pkgType = "binary"
  )

  expect_identical(actual, expected)

  expect_identical(getOption("repos"), expected$repos)
  expect_identical(getOption("pkgType"), expected$pkgType)
})
#> $repos
#>                                                            RSPM 
#> "https://packagemanager.rstudio.com/all/__linux__/focal/latest" 
#>                                                            CRAN 
#>                                   "https://cloud.r-project.org" 
#> 
#> $pkgType
#> [1] "binary"
#> 
#> ── FAILURE (<text>:22:3): Set options ──────────────────────────────────────────
#> `actual` not identical to `expected`.
#> Component "repos": Lengths (2, 1) differ (string compare on first 1)
```

Created on 2021-01-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/) (v0.3.0)

Comment: `options()` returns the old values for the options set in the call? A frequently observed pattern is `old <- options(...); on.exit(options(old))` .

Comment: @krlmlr yes, I thought so too. But even that pattern doesn't seem to be consistent as the return value of my `set_options()` (which is just a wrapper around `options()`) differs in its output (see first and last code block)

Comment: The return value depends on the currently set options, which could be different in the environments you're running it.